# MariaDB cluster, how to make sure nodes are in sync and have the same structure and data

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cluster-computing

I have a mariadb cluster running on three nodes. I noticed last week that some table structures are not identical between the nodes, for example a table has a column that allowed NULL values on node2 and the same table on node1 was NOT NULL.

I checked the cluster health (http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/monitoringthecluster.html) and everything seems to be OK.

My cluster is configured to use "Total Order Isolation" so my understanding is that DDL changes should be replicated on all nodes within the original transaction.

All write and DDL requests are sent to the same node (node1), using HAProxy.

My question is : **how can we monitor if this situation occurs**? 
Is there a tool / mariadb variable available to tell us something is no longer in sync?

My solution so far has been to backup the database on my node1 which seems to be the valid node, delete all tables and apply the backup from node 1. This replicates the database on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice tut : http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/monitoringthecluster.html

It look like that not all nodes are in the cluster. Do you use MaxScale to connect to an active node ?

Comment: All nodes have a status of Joined and Synced. The node count is 3 which is the number of nodes I have installed. If I create a new table the table will be synced on all nodes it's just that I discovered this particular table that was not synced and it kind a raised a red flag ;)

Comment: are you using the root account ?

Comment: To run maridb? No a mysql user account

Comment: sorry, to run your queries as mysql-user root ?

Comment: Yes I usually connect as the root user to have access to all my databases but each database has their own users.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by grabbing

```
mysqldump --no-data
```

from each node.  Then `diff` the output files.

As for "monitoring".  I question how the problem could have occurred in the first place.  Are random people allowed to make tables on random nodes *without* propagating the tables?  Are you using something other than Galera-provided utilities for bringing up a node?